# Use JavaCameraView in other project

Tags: android, android-layout, opencv, android-camera

My question is really simple, I'm trying to launch the ColorBlobDetectionActivity (From OpenCV Sample - color-blob-detection) from an activity in another project, so far all I did was:

- Copy the files ColorBlobDetectionActivity.java and ColorBlobDetector.java into my new project
- Add opencv library - 2.4.3.jar as a referenced library (so far everything is built correctly, no errors detected by eclipse)

The problem starts when I launch ColorBlobDetectionActivity from a button within another activity (The intent is working fine but the activity doesn't start and the cellphone says the unfortunately XXX has stopped).I get this error regarding the JavaCameraView in color_blob_detection_surface_view.xml (which is the view referenced by the activity I'm trying to launch):

```
    The following classes could not be instantiated:
    - org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
    See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
    Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse
```

Answer (score 0):

you should make sure the jar file is properly included in the project.  check in the project properties, java> build path.

also make sure this jar file is in the **libs** folder of your project. if its not in the build path, do right click on it,  > add to build path.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, apparently the classes were included in the OpenCV 2.4.3 library project, so I just had to add a reference to it. The .jar file was properly included in the project so no problems there.